# Elasticity Cobb-Douglas production function

Tags: elasticity, production-function, cobb-douglas

I am given the production function

$y=x_1^\alpha x_2^{1-\alpha}$, where $0< \alpha <1$ I found the demand functions for minimum production cost to be

$ x_1^{*}(w_1,w_2,y)=\left ( \frac{w_2}{w_1}\frac{\alpha}{\beta} \right )^{\frac{\beta}{\alpha +\beta}}y^\frac{1}{{\alpha +\beta}} \; \wedge \; x_2^{*}(w_1,w_2,y)=\left ( \frac{w_1}{w_2}\frac{\beta}{\alpha} \right )^{\frac{\alpha}{\alpha +\beta}}y^\frac{1}{{\alpha +\beta}}$

**Problem**

Now, I have to find the elasticity of $(x_2^*/x_1^*)$ wrt. $w_2/w_1$. I found that $(x_2^*/x_1^*)=\frac{\beta w_1}{\alpha w_2}$ and thus

$\epsilon = \frac{\partial \frac{\beta w_1}{\alpha w_2}}{\partial (w_2/w_1)} \cdot \frac{w_2/w_1}{\frac{\beta w_1}{\alpha w_2}}$

1. Here I end up stuck and do not know how to reduce/evaluate this expression
2. What does the elasticity mean for the total production cost on input 1?

Answer (score 1):

For elasticity calculation why don't you try this:

\begin{align}
\frac{x_2^*}{x_1^*}&=\frac{\beta w_1}{\alpha w_2}  \\
\ln\bigg(\frac{x_2^*}{x_1^*}\bigg) &= c - \ln\bigg(\frac{w_2}{w_1}\bigg) \tag{$c=\ln(\beta/\alpha)$}
\end{align}

It's easy to see from above that elasticity is $-1$

For second part, cost of production:

\begin{align}
C&=w_1x_1^* + w_2x_2^* \\
&=w_1x_1^*(1+\beta/\alpha) \\
&=\frac{w_1x_1^*}{\alpha} \tag{$\beta=1-\alpha$}
\end{align}

So the production cost per unit of input 1 is just the function of $w_1$ (given $\alpha$).

EDIT: As requested for clarification in comments:
Note that elasticity of $y$ w.r.t $x$ is defined as:

\begin{align}
\epsilon &= \frac{\partial y/y}{\partial x/x} \\
&= \frac{\partial \ln y}{\partial \ln x}
\end{align}

So elasticity is simply the slope on the log-scale for $y$ and $x$.

Now substitute $y=x_2^*/x_1^*$ and $x=w_2/w_1$ in your case.

Comment: Not my question but what effect does this have on production cost for input 1?

Comment: @bymathformath: Added some part in answer for second part of the question.

Comment: Greetings. i am not a 100% confideny on how to use the log of the expression to find the derivative term in the elasticity

Comment: Elasticity is of $y$ w.r.t. $x$ is $d(\ln y)/d(\ln x)$. So it's just the slope on the log scale.

Comment: $y$ wrt to $x$? are you saying that $\frac{\partial \frac{\beta w_1}{\alpha w_2}}{\partial (w_2/w_1)} =d(ln(y))/d (ln (x))$? Could you please show how you compute this because I am fairly confused now.

Comment: I added some details in the answer for clarification

Comment: But in the clarification I end up with the same source for my confusion (which I should have clarified). I dont know how to compute such a derivative i.e $\frac{\partial ln(x_2^*/x_1^*)}{\partial ln(w_2/w_1)}$. (the fact that the  derivative is of respect to a variable that is not included confuses me (since $w_2/w_1$ and not $w_1/w_2$ as in the  $(x_2^*/x_1^*)$)

Comment: $$\frac{x_2^*}{x_1^*}=\frac{\beta w_1}{\alpha w_2} = \frac{\beta/\alpha}{w_2/w_1}$$. Now is it clear?

Comment: yes I think! I would then end up with the elasticity $-\frac{\beta}{\alpha(w_2/w_1))^2}\cdot\frac{w_2/w_1}{(\beta w_1)/(\alpha w_2)}$. Is this correct (I have not found it to $-1$ yet)

Comment: The whole point of taking $\ln$ was to avoid this calculation. Just take $\ln$ on both sides of the equation that I have mentioned in my previous comment. In any case if you are not familiar with log transformation and derivatives that much then you can use your approach. On simplifying your expression further you will get $-1$.

Comment: Yes I see. I am - normally - pretty good with derivatives but not that faimiliar with log transformation. I will try to simplify my newly found equation to $-1$. Thanks for the help!

Comment: By the chain rule $\frac{\partial \log f(x)}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial log(x)} \frac{\partial \log x}{ \partial x}$ this implies that $\frac{1}{f(x)} \frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial \log f(x)}{\partial \log x} \frac{1}{x}$ therefore $\frac{\partial \log f(x)}{\partial \log x} = \frac{x}{f(x)} \frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x}$ which is definition of elasticity of $f(x)$ with respect to $x$. Offcourse $x>0$ to take $\log$.

Comment: @Dayne the second question that is formulated as "What does the elasticity signify for the portion of total production cost that is used on input 1"  I see your "cost of prodution" but where is the elasticity used and/or explained since I am having a hard time relating the elasticity to the portion of total production cost that is used on input 1.